# Search and replace apostrophes using regex in VI

Tags: regex, vim, vi

I am trying to search and replace all occurrences of backslashes followed by a single quote to one backslash and quote. Like this:

`Everyone\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'s` to `Everyone\'s`  in VI.

It should also replace: `blah\\\\\\\'\'` to `blah\'\'`

I am unable to fiqure it out how to do it.

tried : `:%s/\\\+\'/\\'/` but it only works for the first one.

I also tried: `:%s/\\\+?\'/\\'/` but this dont work.

What should be the correct REGEX for it?.

Comment: why the result of `Everyone..` example has no slash? your requirement is: `place all occurrences of backslashes followed by a single quote to one backslash and quote.`

Comment: Sorry its an typo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for your requirement:

> replace all occurrences of backslashes followed by a single quote to
>   **one backslash and quote**.

```
 %s/\\\+'/\\'/g
```

your two examples:

```
Everyone\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'s -> Everyone\'s
blah\\\\\\\'\' -> blah\'\'
```

tested with vim 7.3

Comment: thanks, worked for me.. weirs was not working in night .. :^)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
%s/[\\\\]*'/'/
```

<strike>Note that the code tag crushed the four instances of '\' down to two: there are four backslashes inside the brackets.</strike>

Thanks for fixing, Rohit!